# sql developer sqldeveloper-21.2.1.204.1703-x64 is crashing - Error 126

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

sql developer version (sqldeveloper-21.2.1.204.1703-x64) of sqldeveloper.exe is crashing with this error:

```
LoadLibrary failed with error 126: The specified module could not be found.
```

The error happens every single time using the program for about one minute or so.

(Note: Some people have mentioned to change device manager settings/display settings.  I do not have access to do that and have been told that I cannot change those settings)

I have been running "jstack.exe" to see if I get some debug information but it does not show anything relevant to that error.

Any ideas?

## Details

```
Java Version (This is the version that came with sqldeveloper)
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b09, mixed mode)
```

Windows Version:

[image: windows10]

Screen Shots:

The actual error message:

[image: loadlibraryfailed]

Running it directly from command prompt, after clicking on "Ok" in above message, just returns back:

[image: sqldeveloper.exe]

Comment: there should be more to the error stack than that...can you start SQLDev from a cmd prompt, and run the EXE in the bin folder? A;sp. wjat PS and what Java are you running?

Comment: Jeff, thank you for your response!  Please see above, I have updated the question with the requested information.

Comment: That error dialog/message looks like it comes from the launcher before the VM is started (probably while starting the VM). Some windows environment issue is causing a DLL not to be found (or a wrong version found) would be my guess. So first thing I would try is actually installing Oracle JDK 11 (11.0.11), and tell SQLDev to use that JDK and see if it helps

Comment: I've solved this, look at my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74996959/pyinstaller-failing-to-find-sdl2-when-creating-an-exe-for-a-python-kivy-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestion but I was not allowed to install another version of Java on this machine.  This seems to me like a bug and the program should be fixed, not circumventing by adding more software onto your system.  It should work out of the box as soon as I download it.

I have now found a solution, the solution is I will use TOAD for now until Oracle can get their act together.